# Is that any Next function for a foreach in KeyValuePair?

Tags: c#

Is that any Next function for a foreach in KeyValuePair ?

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<class>> KPV in dic )
{  }
```

or the only solution is using the traditional for loop with counter

Comment: I haven't the slightest idea what you're asking.

Comment: what do you want to do with `KeyValuePair<T,U>.Next`. It does not represent any set which can be iterated. For anything else, foreach is sufficient.

Comment: As @Tilak mentions, a KeyValuePair has no notion of a collection. Next would not make any sense in regards to a KeyValuePair instance. Perhaps you should state the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I think he is asking if there is a way to loop through all items in a dictionary using foreach instead of for.

Comment: and my interpretation is, he want to do nested looping for `List<class>`

Comment: The thing with KeyValuePairs is that it isn't a list. It's a dictionary entry. It doesn't make sense to have access to the next one.

Answer (score 3):

Read [MSDN Dictionary Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> Represents a collection of keys and values.

While iterating through the dictionary, you work with [KeyValuePair Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx), which represents a pair of key (here `string`) and value (here `List<T>`). So if the intention is to loop through `List<T>` in each pair, you need to access [KeyValuePair.Value Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224761.aspx):

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<object>> KPV in dic)
{
    foreach (object v in KPV.Value)
    {

    }
}
```

Also I replaced `List<class>` with `List<object>`, as definitely `class` is not a possible name for a type.

If each [KeyValuePair.Key Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224760.aspx) value is not important you may iterate through [Dictionary.Values Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx):

```
foreach (List<object> values in dic.Values)
{
    foreach (object v in values)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` objects can be enumerated *if* they are inside a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` object.

Inside a `Dictionary` you can use the [`Dictionary.Enumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3z2hhax.aspx) structure, which exposes the [`Dictionary.Enumerator.MoveNext()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab0k6d6s.aspx) method, which may be the "Next" function you are looking for.

It would be nice if you can tell us what you intend to do inside that `foreach` code block.